# Dell SP2309w not getting full resolution on Inspiron E1505

Tags: windows-7, display, dell-inspiron

HI Folks, i have an Inspiron E1505 with Windows 7 and Intel GMA 945 Chipset. I connected a Dell SP2309W 23" monitor via VGA to the laptop but it is not achieving it's original resolution but is stuck at 1024 x 768. Also it is detected as a Generic Non PNP Display Device. I upgraded my display driver to latest version and it fully supports Windows 7. What more can i do?
Any help.
Thanks a Lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the W7 Driver for the Display, it may not correct the problem, but it will allow Device manager and your Graphics driver correctly identify the monitor and its resolution capabilities.

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?releaseid=R229399&formatcnt=1&libid=0&fileid=331172

.